# Expand CreatedBy Email in OOTB list view in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view, email, excel

While exporting a list/library to excel using ribbon option, we can see only CreatedBy user's Display name.

Any idea how can I expand CreatedBy to CreatedBy:Email in OOTB list view in SharePoint 2013, so that it gets captured in Export to Excel as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the column settings there is section as show field, in there select Work email in dropdown and then try. You should get the email. But this is only for the People picker fields which you create. The other pre defined fields like Created By and Modified By cant have the email as they are read only and have predefined structure to follow. 
However you can run scripts/powershell commands to get the email from Created By and Modified By field.

Comment: I'm able to get email address of Created By through powershell, However I want this feature to be available to end users through browser

Comment: You can create a coulumn and then extend the script to add that value (email id) in the column

Comment: Can you please elaborate what kind of script, will it need periodic updating?

Comment: it can be a event reciever which will update the column on Item Adding/ Updated